# Using MPMoviePlayerViewController full screen in iPad app that's not fully ported from iPad...yet

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an iPhone app that launched the good old MPMoviePlayerController with a movie file.  I changed it to a MPMoviePlayerViewController and used presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated to get the movie to play on the iPad.  It looks awful with the 2x sized controls.  Can this be coded in such a way that it will look good regardless of which device?  This is just an intermediate thing, but I need to get it going quickly.

Thanks for any pointers.